# Actual display size of IOS fonts doesn't match metrics

Tags: ios, fonts

I am writing an iPad app which requires letters to be displayed at their exact point size regardless of screen size.
I've implemented the text display using a UILabel object. I have the Autoshrink property set to Fixed Font Size, however the letters on the screen are much smaller than indicated by the font metrics. For instance the capitals of a 251 point font, which should be 3.5 inches tall, are only 2 inches on the screen. At different point sizes the same shrinkage happens.
The fontCapHeight is the same as the font size with the font I am using.
How can I make the displayed size is the same as the font size?

Answer (score 0):

> For instance the capitals of a 251 point font, which should be 3.5 inches tall, are only 2 inches on the screen.

You're assuming a point is 1/72", which is not true. That's a desktop publishing point. A point in iOS is a certain number of pixels (based on the scale). The number of pixels in an inch are a factor of the screen's pixel density (PPI). iOS provides no way to query for that that I'm aware of. You have to just have a big table that knows. A fairly nice one for that is [GBDeviceInfo](https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBDeviceInfo), but ultimately it just has a big table of values based on looking up specs or measuring screens.

You need your cap height (pt) to be `(ppi/scale)*inches`, but you can't set cap height directly. You need to set it via the em box size (the "font size"). Here's an example. It takes a label containing a font of any size and make it's cap height be 3".

```
    let font = label.font!

    let ppi = 326.0 // iPhone 6s
    let scale = Double(UIScreen.main.scale)
    let desiredSize = 3.0 // inches

    let emBoxRatio = Double(font.pointSize / font.capHeight)

    let fontSize = (ppi / scale) * desiredSize * emBoxRatio

    label.font = label.font.withSize(CGFloat(fontSize))
```

Keep in mind that "make its cap height be 3 inches" is not the same thing as "make any particular letter be 3 inches." It depends on the font and the letter. In many fonts, glyphs with a curved top are a little taller than the cap height, and some ascenders may be a little taller than the cap height. While H, X, and I are often exactly the cap height, sometimes they're a little shorter (sometimes O is the cap height rather than X). Sometimes glyphs are above their baseline. There is nothing that says that a font even has to fit within its em box, and some fonts draw wildly outside (Zapfino, I'm looking at you).

My only point here is that you need to check your actual font carefully. Font metrics are serving suggestions at best. They're meant to make fonts with similar metrics "feel" the same. They're not always absolute measures of things.

I don't understand this:

> The fontCapHeight is the same as the font size with the font I am using

If the cap height is the same as the "font size" (em box height), then where are the descenders? It feels like you've run out of em box.

Comment: Thank for the clarification Rob. Since posting, I added a filled rectangle with 251 point sides to the view, and it displays at exactly the same size as the letters (which are all fixed height with no descenders in the font in question). So the problem is as you stated, that points don't correlate to any real world measurement even though the documentation seems to say that they do. I suspect that the only work around is to physically measure the dimensions on the device screen and set the logical dimensions in proportion. At least the measurements seem the same for all screen sizes I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I found the following statement at http://blog.fluidui.com/designing-for-mobile-101-pixels-points-and-resolutions/  : "An iOS point is equivalent to 1/163 of an inch. This size is always the same regardless of the resolution of the phone it is on, and comes from the 163DPI of the original iPhone." I couldn't find it anywhere in the Apple documentation, but I'm sure it is there somewhere!